# Can't rebuild R.java each time I close Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, r.java-file

I know that there is a lot of question about problems with R.java, but I couldn't find a good answer to my exact problem.

I have a project that works well. But as soon as I close and reopen Eclipse, it stops resolving R.java. Then, if I clean the project, it won't rebuild the file. The only solution I found is the following :

- Delete project folder and .metadata folder.
- reimport project
- then it works fine

But you do understand that this is not fun for me to do this each time I want to close Eclipse. And I sometime need to close Eclipse ;)

And of course :

- I checked that all my XML are fine
- I tried to clean/rebuild project a lot of times before
- I tried to just reimport project, and it wasn't working
- I don't have this problem with other simplier projects.

Any clues?

Comment: Is eclipse set to 'build automatically'? Project -> Build Automatically

Comment: Most of the time yes, but I already tried to uncheck it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look like it was a bug of ADT 21.0.1! Basicly, it couldn't build my project because it was containing ".SVN" folders. Moreover, I was getting an build error each time I wanted to export my Android App. I downloaded the new 21.1 version, and it solved the problem!

Here is more details about this bug :
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=42051

It says that it is on Windows 7, but I'm on Mac OS X and I got the same problem.